# AssertionError: 404 != 200 Failure in Django

Tags: python, django

I wrote test for all aspects of my model, but the very simple and basic one fails. Here is the `urls.py`

```
app_name = 'projects'
urlpatterns = [
    path('all/', ViewProjects.as_view(), name='all_projects'),
    path('project/<slug:project_slug>/',
         ProjectDetail.as_view(), name='project_detail'),
    path('new/', ProjectCreateView.as_view(), name='project_create'),
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

and its respective test:

```
class TestProject(TestCase):
    def test_project_list_view(self):
        url = reverse('projects:home')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

This test gets failed, here is the traceback:

```
(Portfolio) PS D:\GitHub\Portfolio> python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
.[2020-09-20 21:34:36,616] log: WARNING - Not Found: /
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_project_list_view (projects.tests.TestProject)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\GitHub\Portfolio\projects\tests.py", line 11, in test_project_list_view
    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 404 != 200

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.113s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

However, when I run `python manage.py runserver` the urls, views and template are all connected. What is the problem? Please help thank you.

edit:

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'projects'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['projects'] = Project.objects.all()
        react = get_object_or_404(Category, title='reactjs')
        context['react_projects'] = Project.objects.filter(
            category__title=react.title)
        django = get_object_or_404(Category, title='django')
        context['django_projects'] = Project.objects.filter(
            category__title=django.title)
        context['featured_blogs'] = Blog.objects.filter(featured=True)
        return context
```

Comment: What does the `GET` for your `HomeView` do? Is it using something like `get_object_or_404` which can result in a 404? (Note that your tests use their own database, not the one your app runs with.)

Comment: I just added the view, I am checking the request status code only and also I created its own database too, none worked. I tried all possible ways I know.

Comment: There seems to be no issue with your code. Your test fails because in your view you called `get_object_or_404` to find some data in your database which does not exist due to the fact that django test uses a test database which is clear after each test. so for your code to run properly you have to manually populate those data for example in `Category` model

Answer (score -1):

IT seems that you do not have any fixtures in the test Database when you run tests.
The method 'get_context_data' is used 'get_object_or_404' it seems that one of the classes mentioned does not have any instances so you run on this assertion error.
Sometimes you can encounter this error when the reverse URL is set wrong.